# How do I keep the XAML editor in Visual Studio (2015) from inserting useless extra quotes after attribute values?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

If I type some attribute:

```
Width="40"
```

then as soon as I enter the first quote, VS helpfully adds the second. However if I then want to add another attribute, what do I naturally do? Type the second quote! But then I get:

```
Width="40""
```

This is in contrast with the C# editor's handling of parentheses; the close parens I type overwrite the autogenerated ones. Of course I can just press the right arrow key or the end key, but that just feels unnatural...

How can I disable this "feature" without completely turning off intellisense in the XAML editor? Is there an extension which fixes this? I think the C# editor does the same thing for quotes, too, but I notice it more with XAML for some reason...

Comment: I don't really get your problem. When you start typing an attribute, you get the option in the intellisense popup and you just press enter, then you have the attribute with both quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> XAML -> Miscellaneous -> Auto Insert -> Attribute Quotes

Comment: Thanks! I'll go try that out when I get a chance!

Comment: That worked perfectly! And interestingly enough, pressing tab after typing the attribute value filled in the close quote AND end tag immediately - even though the auto-insert is turned off! :D